# system function usage from Rstudio in linux environment

Tags: r, rstudio

I have the below line in my R script which is working when I invoke R from command line in Linux environment,

```
system('spectre run.scs -f psfascii +l mylog.txt >> /dev/null')
```

[image]

But the same line is not working when I run this script by launching RStudio from the command line,

[image]

[image]

spectre is a valid command which works when R is invoked, but when rstudio the command is not getting recognized.

Point to Note: The spectre command is from an external module apart from R, which I have loaded in the linux terminal like below before calling R and rstudio.

[image]

**EDITED with PATH from R and RStudio**

When I run which spectre from the command line and check its path,

[image]

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/tool/eda/apps/synopsysHspice/2013.03-SP2/hspice/bin:/tool/eda/apps/synopsysHspice/2013.03-SP2/hspice/arch:/tool/eda/apps/mentorCalibre/2014.2_33.25/aoi_cal_2014.2_33.25/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceMMSIM/13.11.292/tools/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceMMSIM/13.11.292/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceICOA/6.1.6.500.11/share/oa/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceICOA/6.1.6.500.11/tools/dfII/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceICOA/6.1.6.500.11/tools/bin:/tool/pandora64/bin:/tool/pandora64/sbin:/tool/pandora/bin:/tool/pandora/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin"
```

But when I check the path in R studio,

[image]

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/tool/pandora64/.package/qt-5.5.1/bin:/tool/pandora64/.package/R-3.4.3/bin:/tool/pandora64/.package/rstudio-99.9.9/app/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceMMSIM/13.11.292:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceMMSIM/13.11.292"
```

Comment: On the shell command line (neither R nor RStudio), type in `which spectre`. Whatever path it gives you, use that full path in RStudio. You can see how they are different by analyzing `Sys.getenv("PATH")` in both the R and the RStudio repl loops to see that the latter is likely operating on a smaller (or at least different) list.

Comment: @r2evans Yes I could see that the PATH in R and Rstudio are different. I have attached the different paths that I'm seeing in the Q. Can you advise how to change the path in Rstudio?

Comment: `Sys.setenv(PATH="....new_path...")`, or more simply just use the full in system, as in `system('/path/to/spectre .....')`.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was suggested by @r2evans from the comment section,

Changed the PATH in Rstudio by copying the path from R environment in command line,

```
 Sys.setenv(PATH="/tool/eda/apps/synopsysHspice/2013.03-SP2/hspice/bin:/tool/eda/apps/synopsysHspice/2013.03-SP2/hspice/arch:/tool/eda/apps/mentorCalibre/2014.2_33.25/aoi_cal_2014.2_33.25/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceMMSIM/13.11.292/tools/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceMMSIM/13.11.292/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceICOA/6.1.6.500.11/share/oa/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceICOA/6.1.6.500.11/tools/dfII/bin:/tool/eda/apps/cadenceICOA/6.1.6.500.11/tools/bin:/tool/pandora64/bin:/tool/pandora64/sbin:/tool/pandora/bin:/tool/pandora/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin")
```